# Pdo undefined index and invalid parameter number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I´m trying to develop a basic search system and I´m getting an issue with my pdo statement adding my $_SESSION to the sql statement.

**Errors Im getting:**

**Notice: Undefined index: where in ->** $readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from news $_SESSION[where]  ORDER BY data");

**Warning: PDOStatement::execute():** SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in  **->**  $readNews->execute();

Somebody there see something that Im doing wrong?

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
    {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Title:')
        {
            $_SESSION['where'] = "WHERE title LIKE ?";
        }
        else
        {
            unset($_SESSION['where']);
        }

    }
```

PDO statement:

```
    $readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from news $_SESSION[where]  ORDER BY date");  
    $readNews->bindValue(1, "%$search%");
    $readNews->execute();
```

I already did this with normal mysql, like this and **its working:**

"select * from news {$_SESSION[where]} ORDER BY date DESC";

But now I´m trying to do with PDO..

Comment: It looks like the `?` in your `WHERE title LIKE ?` requires some sort of string to pass into it, and is likely causing your problem

Comment: if it works with with old mysql then it works with PDO as well. your problem is with session, not PDO. If you didn't notice yet

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I dont see where the session problem is, for me looks correct!

Comment: It says in plain English: **Undefined index: where**. Means you HAVE problem with session, where such index you expect.

Comment: I know that, I´m just dont understanding why my session array is empty!

Comment: there can be several reasons. one, for example, is a line of here code that does unset()

Answer (score 1):

**Undefined index: where** means there is no such item in your $_SESSION array

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION[where]`  should be `{$_SESSION['where']}`

Other wise interpreter try to find `where` as constant.

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm']))
    {
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        if(!empty($search) && $search != 'Title:')
        {
            $_SESSION['where'] = "WHERE title LIKE ?";
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['where']='';//changed here because you are trying to access it
        }

    }
```

and

```
$readNews = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from news {$_SESSION['where']}  ORDER BY date");
```

Comment: Thanks but I already tried with: {$_SESSION['where']} andn I have the same problem!

Comment: why don't  interpreter find `from` or `news` as constant?

Comment: And like that I have 1 more error: Use of undefined constant where

Comment: @YourCommonSense may you see the out of this `<?php session_start();$_SESSION['where']='yes';echo $_SESSION[where];`.

Comment: Is for a basic search system, search for the title of my news registered on my database!

Comment: Now you managed to solve one error message. But there is anoter

Comment: @YourCommonSense I wanted to show you that if we use `$_SESSION[where]` and `where` is not defined as constant then you will always get a notice.

Comment: If i remove my pdo statments When I write in the search input something then with the echo $_SESSION[where] Im getting what I write!

Comment: Problem solved! It was only to put the search value stored in session $_SESSION['where'] = "WHERE titulo LIKE '%$search%'";

Comment: I just thought that width PDO we needed to bind all values used in the sql statment.

Comment: What a strange situation, it is working but I have the errors anyway!!

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about it.

Comment: yes, you will get some E_Notice if you  use `$_SESSION[where]` instead of `$_SESSION['where']` .

Comment: @John23 yes, you **should** bind all values

Comment: @AmitGarg as you can see it doesn't always show a notice. You need to read PHP manual better. You tried to solve nonexistent problem than has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @John23 you need to understand your code better. It DOESN'T work. Upvote you gave to this answer is undeserverd

Comment: Thanks for your advices Your Common Sense, but the code actually works, I just have that error message and Im trying to understand why, but he code works! And with normal mysql dont give any error message!

Comment: @John23 this is your problem. You can't even test your code if it works. "Works" means works in every mode, not just one. And refusing to see the obvious you're making things even worse. One little advise: first of all, try to understand what does this error message mean. It will tell you a lot, when you learn it's meaning

Comment: @John23 and even prior it you have to understand thet every error has it's *meaning*. It is not just like an unwanted obstacle, but a friendly advisor, helping you to make your code work. Means you have to listen to it. And then fix the error, not message.

Comment: Thanks for your attention! And I have realized what is happening, when I write something in my search input messages and I submit, I dont get any error because I'm giving values ​​to my $search variable.

Comment: The problem is that when I'm not passing any value to search my $search then the sql command needs the value of $search and then because I did not pass this value I´v got the error saying that no such variable is defined. My only problem is to understand how I can fix it!